# Why fitting a function the indexing of an array can possibly change in Python?

Tags: python, range, curve-fitting

This is my first python related question here. I noted a vagary in a code of mine while trying to fit some data to a function. Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    import math

    def arr(x,a,b):
        return a*np.exp(-b*x)

    def main():
        x = np.loadtxt('slopex.txt', usecols=(1,0))
        fig=plt.figure(1)
        popta, pcova = curve_fit(arr, x[0:4,0], x[0:4,1])
        print(popta)
    main()
```

The problem is that the shape of my x array is (5,2), but if write x[0:4,0], x[0:4,1], or either x[:,0], x[:,1] to select the range of interest  my fitting coefficients are changing. What is going on with the indexing?
As a matter of fact if I try `print(x[5:0])` I still get `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5` and that's all right but confusing.

Thank you all in advance, I hope I have been clear enough. I looked for this one on the internet but I couldn't find it myslef, hence I am asking you guys!

Comment: On why Python uses 0-based indexing and half-open intervals see Guido van Rossum's [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20190321101606/https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in python indices are not inclusive of the last element:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([[0,0]]*5)
print(x[0:4,0].shape)
>>>(4,)
print(x[:,0].shape)
>>>(5,)
```

They work just like the range function so this works:

```
list(range(10))[0:10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also just to clear up your x[5:0,0] will not work, element 5 is out of bounds as the indexes start at 0 len([0,1,2,3,4])=5. but also you need to specify that the step should be in the negative direction: x[4:0:-1,0]. as before the first element will not be included, you just need to leave it blank to get it included: x[4::-1,0], will return all the elements of the first column in reverse order.

Comment: exactly what you did type: x[0:4,0] or for all but the last element x[0:-1,0].